# Is there any way to DRY my Objective-C iOS ViewControllers?

Tags: ios5, xcode4, objective-c-2.0

I have a group of controllers, most of whom share similar functionality.

For example:

- Controller A has method 1 and method 2.
- Controller B has method 2 and method 3.
- Controller C has method 1 and method 3.

Subclassing is not really an option here as I specifically don't want Controller B to have method 1.

Protocols are not really ideal either; They still require me to define duplicates of my methods in each controller.

Is there no way to define a method in one place and mix this functionality into classes as and when required in Objective C?

Comment: I'm curious. Can you explain how it would be a problem if controller B had a method with the same signature as method 1?

Answer (score 1):

Use blocks! https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502

Comment: Thanks for the tip... where is the best place to define a block that can be accessed from multiple files? Just in a `blocks.m` file and import `blocks.h` to the classes that require it?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is not to use a class at all. Since I guess those methods require to access some of your controllers' fields, you can use a function that receive as a parameter a pointer to a `UIViewController` and access its fields from inside the function. 
If each method should behave in a slightly different way depending if you are working with a `ControllerA`,`ControllerB` or `ControllerC`, then you can use `isKindOfClass` method. For example:

```
    void method1(UIViewController* controller) {
        if( [(id) controller isKindOfClass:[ControllerA class]] ) {
             //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you have ControllerA subclass M1 and M2? Objective C does not support multiple inheritance. Did you have something in mind to work in that context?

Comment: @Jim actually I made a very big mistake. You're completely right, Objective-C does not support multiple inheritance. I edited my answer. Guess I'm really tired today.

Comment: It's okay. I do that often, and fear some troll will immediately downvote. I've got your back :)